# Apple Mail, I can't delete smart folder! There is immortal one!

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I can't delete one of my Smart Folder. Why does Apple Mail refuse delete it? How can I delete this bad one?

Comment: lol i love that last phrasing "There is immortal one!" next internet meme perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is a corrupt plist that you have preventing you from deleting that immortal (lol) Smart Folder.

Edit the Smart Mailboxes plist and removing the (corrupt ?) entries manually. The file is located at ~/Library/Mail/SmartMailboxes.plist.